# STL objects use C Runtime Library locale for floating point conversion, when using _ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, thread-safety, locale

The C Runtime locale is set by `setlocale`.
The Standard C++ Library (STL) locale is set by the `std::locale` class and can be set on individual STL objects like std::istringstream etc.

The function `_configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE)` allows setting the C Runtime locale on a per thread basis.

Unfortunately it seems that STL objects in threads where `_configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE)` is enabled is using the C Runtime locale. Or at least using the decimal point of the C Runtime locale.

In threads without `_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE` there are no problems.

Something similar was asked by Paavo in 2008, but with no answers: [_configthreadlocale and localeconv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276030)

The following code shows the problem:

```
//Enable per thread locale in current thread  
_configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE)  

//Create istringstream object  
std::istringstream LibraryStream;  
//Create double object  
double Value = 0;  
//Create std::locale object with "C" locale ("." as decimal point)  
std::locale StreamLoc("C");  
//Set C Runtime locale to danish ("," as decimal point)  
setlocale(LC_ALL, "danish");  

//Set the "C" locale on the istringstream object  
LibraryStream.imbue(StreamLoc);  
//Get the locale of the istringstream object for test (returns "C" as expected)  
std::locale NewStreamLoc = LibraryStream.getloc();  

//Set floating point string with "C" locale decimal point in istringstream object  
LibraryStream.str("60.258351");  
//Convert the string to double  
LibraryStream >> Value;  

//Now the expected value of "Value" is 60.258351, but it is 60.000  
//when debugging the conversion, I can see that "," is used as decimal point
```

Have anyone experienced this before? Am I doing something wrong? Are there any suggestions for solutions?

Thanks in advance
/TEB

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting code samples, you can use the little `101101` button above the edit field to get the code formatted properly.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++ Standard Library only recently gained knowledge of threads, this apparent dichotomy does not surprise me.  There is an exhaustive discussion of what happens in different scenarios (Microsoft-specific, but seems to be helpful as general background) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235302.aspx).

In summary:

> To change the locale using the C++
>   Runtime Library, use the locale Class.
>   By calling the locale::global method,
>   you change the locale in every thread
>   that has not explicitly enabled
>   per-thread locale. To change the
>   locale in a single thread or portion
>   of an application, simply create an
>   instance of a locale object in that
>   thread or portion of code.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not an expert at locales, so this may be wrong.

On the [Multithreading and Locales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235302%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Knowlegde Base article it is noted:

> Calling locale::global changes the
>   locale for both the Standard C++
>   Library and the C Runtime Library.
>   However, calling setlocale only
>   changes the locale for the C Runtime
>   Library; the Standard C++ Library is
>   not affected.

You are indeed using the C++ Std Lib, so it seemed to me that you needed to call `locale::global()`.  When I did this, the return value is as you expected.  Here is my sample code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //Enable per thread locale in current thread  
    int n = _configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE)  ;

    //Create istringstream object  
    std::istringstream LibraryStream;  
    //Create double object  
    double Value = 0;  
    //Create std::locale object with "C" locale ("." as decimal point)  
    std::locale StreamLoc("C");  
    //Set C Runtime locale to danish ("," as decimal point)  
    char* ret = setlocale(LC_ALL, "danish");  

    //Set the "C" locale on the istringstream object  
    LibraryStream.imbue(StreamLoc);  
    locale::global(StreamLoc);
    //Get the locale of the istringstream object for test (returns "C" as expected)  
    std::locale NewStreamLoc = LibraryStream.getloc();  

    //Set floating point string with "C" locale decimal point in istringstream object  
    LibraryStream.str("60.258351");  
    //Convert the string to double  
    LibraryStream >> Value;  

        //Now the expected value of "Value" is 60.258351, but it is 60.000  
    //when debugging the conversion, I can see that "," is used as decimal point  
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right that calling locale::global() will change the locale for both the Standard C++ Library and the C Runtime Library.

Comment: However I would like to keep the locale for the C Runtime Library and only use the locale on the specific STL object (istringstream LibraryStram) using the imbue() method.

Comment: Does `operator>> Value` use the locale in the stream, or the global locale?

Answer (score 0):

Good point John Dibling. I have tested that and the operator>> Value does use the locale in the stream and not the global locale. It was tested by the example below:

_configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE), removed
locale::global(locale("danish"));, added to set the global Std lib locale

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Enable per thread locale in current thread  
    //int n = _configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE)  ;

    //Create istringstream object  
    std::istringstream LibraryStream;  
    //Create double object  
    double Value = 0;  
    //Create std::locale object with "C" locale ("." as decimal point)  
    std::locale StreamLoc("C");  
    //Set C Runtime locale to danish ("," as decimal point)  
    char* ret = setlocale(LC_ALL, "danish");

    //Set Std lib global locale to "danish"
    locale::global(locale("danish"));

    //Set the "C" locale on the istringstream object  
    LibraryStream.imbue(StreamLoc);  

    //Get the locale of the istringstream object for test (returns "C" as expected)  
    std::locale NewStreamLoc = LibraryStream.getloc();  

    //Set floating point string with "C" locale decimal point in istringstream object  
    LibraryStream.str("60.258351");  
    //Convert the string to double  
    LibraryStream >> Value;  

    //In this case the value of "Value" is 60.258351, as expected and thus  
    //the "C" locale was use for conversion  
}
```

I guess the conclusion so far is that STL objects in threads where  _configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE) is enabled is indeed using the C Runtime  locale.

It is possible to work around this by setting both the Std lib locale and the C Runtime  locale with the locale::global() call. But as Std lib locale is not thread safe and not affected by the _ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE, we can still run in to multithreading problems with this workaround.