# Windows per-thread locales trash the classic locale?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, thread-safety, locale

For reasons I don't understand, my single-threaded program is losing track of the classic (or "C") locale when I ask Windows to store locale information on a per-thread basis. Here's my source code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void print_pt_5()
{
    const int precision = 6;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss.imbue(std::locale::classic());
    //oss.imbue(std::locale("C"));
    oss.setf(std::ios::floatfield, std::ios::fixed);
    oss.precision(precision);
    oss << 0.5;
    printf("%s\n", oss.str().c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    print_pt_5();
    // locale settings are thread-local
    _configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE); 
    // set to german locale
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "German_Austria.850");                
    print_pt_5();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it like this, the output is:

```
0.500000
0,500000
```

If I remove the _configthreadlocale line, the output is:

```
0.500000
0.500000
```

I'm building with VS2012 and running on Windows 8. Why am I getting a comma for the decimal point in the first example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [STL objects use C Runtime Library locale for floating point conversion, when using \_ENABLE\_PER\_THREAD\_LOCALE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145696/stl-objects-use-c-runtime-library-locale-for-floating-point-conversion-when-usi)

Comment: The duplicate I linked to explains.

Comment: I don't think that's it because I'm always imbueing the ostringstream instance with the classic or C locale. I don't think I should ever see a comma for a decimal point.